# How to properly set up YAML flow style dumping using round-trip with ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am working with the ruamel.yaml package and I can't seem to get it to output in a nicely formatted flow style. I'd like to keep elements on the same level separated by trailing commas and newlines. I also would like to preserve every comment, and it seems that some disappear after converting to flow style. Here is an example:

#### Original

```
background_opacity: 0.9 # comment
cursor: {style: Beam}

# comment
font:
    normal: {family: Fira Code, style: Retina} # comment
    size: 12.0 # comment
```

#### Intended

```
{
    background_opacity: 0.9, # comment
    cursor: {style: Beam},
    
    # comment
    font: {
        normal: {family: Fira Code, style: Retina}, # comment
        size: 12.0 # comment
    }
}
```

#### Actual

```
{background_opacity: 0.9 # comment
, cursor: {style: Beam}, font: {normal: {family: Fira Code, style: Retina} # comment
, size: 12.0   # comment
}}
```

My code is attached below. I am pretty new to YAML and ruamel.yaml so I apologize for any simple mistakes.

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

def round_trip(sout, sin, idt):
    yaml = YAML()
    assert idt >= 2
    yaml.indent(mapping=idt, sequence=idt, offset=idt-2)
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True

    data = yaml.load(sin)
    if data is not None:
        data.fa.set_flow_style() # needs fixing: commas are not trailing
        yaml.dump(data, sout)
    else:
        print("the file is empty") # needs fixing: should dump original file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be doing anything wrong, but ruamel.yaml doesn't support making that kind of output. It just tries to cram as much of a flow-style allows on a line, and that you get newlines at all is because outputting the comments (which are associated with the mapping keys before them, forces such a line-break.

If your input would not have any comments, then you end up with one or two lines depending on the output width that you set.

You might get a slightly better result if you on loading append a dummy comment to every line, and remove that after dumping, but that will still not get you opening braces on a line of their own.

Currently you are only setting the root level style attribute, that "works" because you have no nested block-style collections. You should do that recursively with something like:

```
def set_style(d, flow):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if flow:
            d.fa.set_flow_style()
        else:
            d.fa.set_block_style()
        for k in d:
            set_style(d[k], flow)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        if flow:
            d.fa.set_flow_style()
        else:
            d.fa.set_block_style()
        for item in d:
             set_style(item, flow)


data = yaml.load(sin)
set_style(data, flow=True)
```

Comment: I see. On the other hand, is there a way to go from a flow style to a "pure" block style? If I wanted to remove all braces and replace that with block style indentation, does ruamel.yaml support that? I have tried `fa.set_block_style()` but that preserves some braces.

Comment: Did you do `fa.set_block_style()` recursively on all dicts and lists? That method only sets the style for the element you call it upon, which worked non-recursively in your example, as that only has block style at the root of the datastructure. Normally the only flow style curly-braces/square-brackets left, should be for empty dict resp. list.

Comment: I don't believe I did, whoops. I called `fa.set_block_style()` non-recursively in the same way I did for flow style. Is there a simple/recommended way to code this?

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ScalarFloat` for the lines `set_style(d[k], flow)` and `set_style(d[item], flow)`. Sorry for being new to Python as well, could you help me resolve this?

I changed `d[k]` to just `d` and `d[item]` to `item` since I want to iterate through the structures and it seems to work, but I'm not sure if the output is what is intended. Is this a proper fix?

Comment: I can't edit my comment above anymore but I don't believe my change is right — I think it changes a copy of the lists/dicts so the original does not get changed. How should I refer to the child elements in a way that I can edit them?

Comment: Yes that is the proper fix.